# Rbenv: Ruby not installed Command 'ruby' not found (AWS t3a Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: rbenv

I'm trying to install Ruby via Rbenv on Ubuntu 18.04 on AWS t3a using these instructions: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-ubuntu-18-04

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y autoconf bison build-essential libssl-dev libyaml-dev libreadline6-dev zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libffi-dev libgdbm5 libgdbm-dev

git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
rbenv install 2.6.3
rbenv global 2.6.3
```

However, after the `rbenv global 2.6.3` part and then run `ruby -v`, I get

`Ruby not installed Command 'ruby' not found`

But when I run `rbenv versions` it tells me `2.6.3` is listed.

How can I install ruby?

Answer (score 2):

Used `screen -d -r` to see the error message which was `uncommon.mk:545: recipe for target 'rdoc' failed`

Found the solution in https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install/issues/223

Instead of:

`rbenv install 2.6.3`

Do:

`RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--disable-install-doc rbenv install 2.6.3`

Comment: I just encountered the same problem building `2.6.3` in a VirtualBox VM with Vagrant. Before arriving here, I found this GitHub Issues thread which was pointing me in the same direction: https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/156 Thanks for posting the exact error message, it helped me find this SO post.

Answer (score 0):

Try 
    `bundle exec ruby`
And should be work

Comment: Invoking `bundle` assumes `ruby` is in the command path.